# SQL выборка дубли связной таблицы

Tags: php, sql

помогите исправить выборку которая считает количество  заказов с авансом 
есть выборка

```
SELECT count(order_id) as order_id, prepay_id
FROM `crm_orders`
LEFT JOIN crm_orders_prepay ON prepay_order_id = order_id
WHERE order_add_date between '2018-10-02 00:00:00' and '2018-10-02 23:59:59'
AND order_city = 7
AND prepay_id is not null
```

но есть проблема что она мне дублирует записи где было более 1 аванса 
к примеру

```
order_id
127000
127001
127002
127002
```

в итоге у меня вместо 3 выдает 4 заказа с авансом подскажите как правильно убрать дубли с таблицы crm_orders_prepay ?

### мне достаточно зафиксировать факт  аванса

помогло решение с count(distinct id_zakaza)

теперь возникла  проблемай с суммой этих заказов

```
SELECT sum(order_cost_sum) as order_cost_sum
FROM `crm_orders`
LEFT JOIN crm_orders_prepay ON prepay_order_id = order_id
WHERE order_add_date between '2018-10-02 00:00:00' and '2018-10-02 23:59:59'
AND order_city = 7
AND prepay_id is not null
```

если повторить sum(distinct order_cost_sum)  то чистит очень много лишнего ,ребята подскажите как побороть сумму ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(поле) - попробуйте

Comment: GROUP BY order_id тоже подойдет

Comment: COUNT без GROUP BY считает количество по таблице, а не по order.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(поле)   и GROUP BY order_id  не корректно  выводит возможно я не правильно их  применяю ?

Comment: Уберите DISTINCT. Добавьте GROUP BY prepay_order_id.

Comment: если у вас есть айди, и оно может дублироватся, то решение `count(distinct id_zakaza)`

Comment: nick_n_a  твое решение мне помогло с количеством ,  но у меня еще есть проблема с сумой может подскажешь как и ее решить  выше описал ?

Answer (score 1):

Решение по сумме следующее

```
select sum(order_cost_sum) as order_cost_sum
  from #crm_orders
 where order_add_date between '2018-10-02 00:00:00' and '2018-10-02 23:59:59'
   and order_city = 7
   and exists (
               select prepay_order_id
                 from #crm_orders_prepay
                where prepay_order_id = #crm_orders.order_id
              )
;
```

есть еще одно решение

```
select sum(order_cost_sum) as order_cost_sum
  from #crm_orders
 where order_add_date between '2018-10-02 00:00:00' and '2018-10-02 23:59:59'
   and order_city = 7
   and order_id in (
                    select prepay_order_id
                      from #crm_orders_prepay
                   )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(order_id) as order_id, prepay_id
FROM `crm_orders`
LEFT JOIN crm_orders_prepay ON prepay_order_id = order_id
WHERE order_add_date between '2018-10-02 00:00:00' and '2018-10-02 23:59:59'
AND order_city = 7
AND prepay_id is not null
group by prepay_id
```